# How to solve “illegal character” error when saving Google Script for Google Analytics

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-analytics

I'm working on automating Google analytics to get results into a google drive dashboard and coming up with an error code in "illegal character.  (line 7, file "code")" How do i fix this problem? Here is the full script. I appreciate the help in advance. Thanks.

```
// Get Data.
var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    tableId,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    'ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:pageviews',
    {‘dimensions’: ‘ga:date’});

// Output to spreadsheet.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
    .setValues(results.getRows());

// Make Sandwich.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if line 7 in the error message is the same line 7 in the code you pasted, but if it is, then it looks like the single quotes are different. Use the straight single quote ('), and not the curvy one.

Here's what I mean:

```
{‘dimensions’: ‘ga:date’});
```

should be

```
{'dimensions': 'ga:date'});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! that worked but another error popped up in line 2. It said a reference error "tableid" is not defined. What do you think about that one? var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(

Comment: What are you passing in to "tableid"? It should be a string in the form "ga:XXXX", where XXXX is the Analytics view (profile) ID .

Comment: Yes I have that in the report configuration in the dashboard with the 8 digit profile ID. should that be added in the script?

Comment: You will need to pass in your parameters to the "results" variable, so the "tableId", "startDate", and "endDate" will need to have real values. Is that what you were asking? Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Not what I asked but the answer I needed! Thank you! What format does the real values come in next to the "startDate" and "endDate"?

Comment: They would both be strings in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". This is a great resource to help you out: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference. 

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it was very helpful. Thanks a lot one more thing there is a Missing : after property ID. (line 3, file "Code") the one with the "tableId" I couldn't find any solutions for it.

Comment: The "id" should be in the format "ga:XXXXXX" (including the "ga:" part).

Comment: Got it! now this code comes up.. Missing ) after argument list. (line 4, file "Code") Pardon all the questions just trying to figure this out for my company haven't done this before.

Comment: Not sure, why don't you post your full code, what you have so far.

Comment: Here is the full code so far:                                        // Get Data.
var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
  "{tableId}=ga:XXXXXX"
  {startDate}=2013-01-01
  {endDate}=2016-01-01
    'ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:pageviews',
   {'dimensions': 'ga:date'});

// Output to spreadsheet.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
    .setValues(results.getRows());

// Make Sandwich.

Comment: Your dates should be enclosed in quotes, as they are strings. I'm assuming you put in the variable names, ie. {tableId}, {startDate}, etc. for me?

Comment: This quotes (") or (') ? Yes I did but still running into errors saying after property is missing in line 3

Comment: Use double quotes to be consistent.

Comment: Got it. I'm pulling the data now but it's in bulk and not separated by monthly basis how do you fix that?

Comment: Sorry, my expertise has run out as I'm not familiar with the API. You could try to use the "sort" parameter. But again, that's just my guess.