# Embed Web App ReferenceError Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to embed a google script web app into a google site and get the error `ReferenceError: "include" is not defined (line 2, file "Code", project "Test Table Maker")`.

I don't have the word "include" anywhere in any of my code. Is this referring to something else? Or should I have "include" defined somewhere?

I did a little looking and it seems like this could be related to the JQuery I'm using. However, that error specifically points to the "Code" file an line 2. There is nothing there. When I check the console of the web app itself, I do see a few errors, but everything functions as expected, just not when I go to embed it

**Google Sites Embed Error**
[image: The Error]

**Console Errors** *(everything on the web app works)*
[image: Console.log Errors]

**First 3 lines of `Code.gs`**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

**HTML CODE:** [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/p5sLcwnq/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p5sLcwnq/ (instead of doing 300+ lines here). That doesn't have the underlying apps-script.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141355/apps-script-sidebar-reference-error-when-using-include

Comment: I saw that one, but I don't have "include" anywhere in the script so I'm not sure what it's referring to.

Comment: I think that your script works. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about it? 1. What condition did you deploy Web Apps? For example, "Execute the app as:" and "Who has access to the app:" are "Me" and "Anyone, even anonymous", respectively. 2. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, how about redeploying Web Apps as new version?

Comment: 1. Execute as "Me" and "Anyone" has access. 
2. I figured I could go back and try it again in a new project, but just wasn't sure if the issue was on my end or GAS.

Comment: What happens if you simply invoke the web app from a browser, bypassing Google Sites? And can you explain how the web app has been embedded?

Comment: Web app works from a browser without a problem (I can go to the page from the link provided). It's embedded via url. I followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_a_web_app_in_new_sites

Comment: I think a simpler [mcve] might help here. As I can't figure out the relationship between the HTML form, Sites, and the link that calls the web app; some of the browser errors seem related to the form ("tableArray not defined") for example, and it would be good to get rid of the noise. But that is a very odd error message, for what appears to be authorisation related! A few more questions/things to try: new or classic sites? Does your Web App use any libraries (and if so can you cut them out)? How about calling the web app from an incognito window?

Comment: New Sites. Basically, I'm pulling data from a spreadsheet, using google apps script HTML Service to render it. Then trying to embed the web app into google sites. I'll work on it. Even when I copied to a new script project and made some changes, I get a new error `Not html file named Index was found. (line 2, file "Code", project "Test Table Maker"` That file definitely exists.

Comment: This is an odd problem, but GAS "line 2" errors do see relatively common, and have a range of causes; see the list below. It might also be worth trying a different PC, different google account, ... eliminate environmental issues.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605580/bad-value-when-trying-to-execute-google-apps-script
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724013/recurring-generic-error-message-google-apps-script
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272501/how-to-solve-illegal-character-error-when-saving-google-script-for-google-anal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to P Burke for pointing me to a question I hadn't seen before.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605580/bad-value-when-trying-to-execute-google-apps-script) the fix from MShoaib91:

"go to : publish > deploy as webapp > select project version to new and update the project."

I was using the "test" version of the latest code.